# Composer dependency from own forked repository

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I have gitlab repository https://gitlab.com/ajkosh/yii2-admin and below is my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "haruatari/yii2-module-app",
    "description": "Empty module application on Yii2",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Viktor Pikaev",
            "email": "haruatari@gmail.com",
            "homepage": "http://haru-atari.com/about"
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:ajkosh/yii2-admin.git"
        }

    ],
    "require": {
         "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.15",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "paulzi/yii2-materialized-path": "^2.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2":"2.0.4",
        "ajkosh/yii2-admin": "dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
      "codeception/codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
    "fxp-asset": {
      "installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
      }
    },
    "process-timeout": 1800},
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "data": "0777",
                    "data/log": "0777",
                    "data/tmp": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to fetch `yii2-admin` from my own repository but I am getting below error when I am running composer update.

> ```
>  Problem 1
>     - The requested package ajkosh/yii2-admin could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Potential causes:
>  - A typo in the package name
>  - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>    see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
>  - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
>
> Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using incorrect package name. On resolving dependencies package name in URL is irrelevant, the only name what matters is package name in `composer.json`. So Composer reads `composer.json` from your [forked repository](https://github.com/ajkosh/yii2-admin/blob/e2b3eea3a4b685f7802f6b84cfa3affe1ba5b6dc/composer.json), and finds name `mdmsoft/yii2-admin`, because you don't changed it after forking. There is no `ajkosh/yii2-admin` at all. You should either update package name in `composer.json` in your fork:

```
{
    "name": "ajkosh/yii2-admin",
    "description": "RBAC Auth manager for Yii2 ",
    "keywords": ["yii", "admin", "auth", "rbac"],
    "type": "yii2-extension",
    ...
```

**Or** use source package name in your `require` section:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "mdmsoft/yii2-admin": "dev-master"
},
```